# what is the typescript type of axios in vue 3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3-typescript with vue-auth package .

for installing vue-auth I need to a file like this

**http/index.ts**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import type { App } from 'vue';
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL;

export default (app:App) => {
    app.axios = axios;
    app.$http = axios;

    app.config.globalProperties.axios = axios;
    app.config.globalProperties.$http = axios;
}
```

and I have type error here as you seen
[image]
what should I do ?

Comment: looks like you need to augment the vue `App` type

Answer (score 0):

From the [Vue 3 Documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html#augmenting-global-properties):

> Some plugins install globally available properties to all component instances via app.config.globalProperties. For example, we may install this.$http for data-fetching or this.$translate for internationalization. To make this play well with TypeScript, Vue exposes a ComponentCustomProperties interface designed to be augmented via TypeScript module augmentation:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

declare module 'vue' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $http: typeof axios
  }
}
```

> We can put this type augmentation in a .ts file, or in a project-wide *.d.ts file. Either way, make sure it is included in tsconfig.json. For library / plugin authors, this file should be specified in the types property in package.json.